how to truncate text with ... when it reaches its visible space
I have a text "This is a very very long long text" that is displayed between the progress indicator and a switch.
I do not want the text to go over the switch, when the text reaches the switch I want it to show ellipsis (...).
I am using a constraint layout/
For the Text, I tried using  maxLines = 1, overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis, but it did not work.
Could you suggest what I can do to achieve this, please?
Code
if (routineTileItem.chargePercentageForIndicator != null) {
    CircularProgressIndicator(
        progress = routineTileItem.chargePercentageForIndicator,
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
        trackColor = Color.Gray,
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .constrainAs(percentageIndicator) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
            }
    )
    Text(
        text = routineTileItem.chargePercentageForText.asComposableString(),
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelSmall,
        color = Color.White,
        modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(percentageText) {
            start.linkTo(percentageIndicator.start)
            end.linkTo(percentageIndicator.end)
            top.linkTo(percentageIndicator.top)
            bottom.linkTo(percentageIndicator.bottom)
        }
    )
}
Text(
    text = routineTileItem.title.uppercase(),
    maxLines = 1,
    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium,
    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
    modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(title) {
        top.linkTo(parent.top)
        start.linkTo(percentageIndicator.end, 8.dp)
    }
)
Switch(
    checked = routineTileItem.checked,
    onCheckedChange = {
        onToggleChanged(routineTileItem.id)
    },
    colors = SwitchDefaults.colors(
        checkedThumbColor = Color.White,
        checkedTrackColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
        uncheckedThumbColor = Color.White,
        uncheckedTrackColor = Color.LightGray
    ),
    modifier = Modifier
        .offset(0.dp, (-8).dp)
        .constrainAs(switch) {
            end.linkTo(parent.end)
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
        }
)

Screenshot

Thanks.

TextOverflow.Ellipsis is still the way to go, you just need to make sure the Text actually sees the necessity to use the ellipsis - which it doesn't because its width isn't constricted. The actual question would be how you can set the width of the Text so that it ends where the switch begins.

You need to connect the end of the text to the start of the switch to make it work.
